# MySQL link 2 ids where one of them is auto_increment

Tags: php, sql, insert

Well I found something that works perfectly but it looks ugly
Is it possible to do this in one query?

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO page(page_name, page_weight)
              VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['weight'])."')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $query2 = "SELECT page_id FROM page WHERE page_id = (SELECT MAX(page_id)  FROM page)";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {
        $query3 = "INSERT INTO content(page_id, content_type)
                   VALUES('".$row['page_id']."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type'])."')";
        $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
    }
```

The page_id from page is auto incremented but page_id from content isn't, is it possible to link them in any way?

**Edit:**

Thanks PLB now I've got this instead now

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO page(page_name, page_weight)
                VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['weight'])."')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $query3 = "INSERT INTO content(page_id, content_type)
                VALUES('".mysql_insert_id()."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type'])."')";
    $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
```

Is it possible to make 1 query of though?

Comment: `mysql_insert_id();` returns last inserted value.

Comment: yes u can link them, have u defined relations between ur tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_insert_id();` returns last inserted id. Using it you can remove select query like this:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO page(page_name, page_weight)
                VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['weight'])."')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

        $query3 = "INSERT INTO content(page_id, content_type)
                    VALUES('".mysql_insert_id()."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type'])."')";
        $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
```

But I suggest stop using `mysql_*` functions and try `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: That helped but is it possible to make just one query of it? Like selecting 2 tables in one insert. Or does this look fine? And for the msqli thing. This is a schoolproject and our teacher does not want to start using mysqli yet.

Comment: @SinanSamet MySql does not support multi-table insertion in a single [INSERT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)

Comment: Okay thanks a lot this was useful! And @jugnu I will take a look at the relation thing I suppose that would be more functional, thank you!